# what does random_state exactly do in DecisionTreeRegressor in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am studying this [post](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/your-first-machine-learning-model).

I've already reproduce the code which is OK.

There is only one thing I cannot completely understand, which is, what does random_state exactly do in DecisionTreeRegressor in sklearn?

The post says "Specify a number for random_state to ensure same results each run" and "model quality won't depend meaningfully on exactly what value you choose", which means, in my understanding, this param does not
make any sense.

You must specify a value for it, you could specify any valid value for it, whatever you specify for it, it doesn't matter! Why does this method provide such a param?

Comment: It does matter. But it's hard to foresee the effects of a given number and therefore you should never tune that value to tune your model. It's just a number which results picking from different random-number sequences. All (in the optimal case) share the same randomness core (e.g. uniform distribution), but the sequence of numbers will be different. This parameter is very important to *control* randomness for reproducing results (when algorithms are based on *pseudo-randomness*). Very different results for two different seeds with non toy-data size would be a very bad sign.

Comment: Random forests have randomness at least in two direction: along features (columns) and along rows (cases). So changing random seed does have impact on the results,